# How do I scroll to the middle of a page at page load?

Tags: html, css, window, centering, pageload

I want that on my artist's website the visitors start from 
the center of the page.

Since the site is large and has experimental content, 
visitors should decide for themselves in which direction 
they want to move on the site. The contents of the page 
on the right and left as well as above and below are 
already partially visible.

Therefore, the page should scroll to the horizontal and 
vertical center when loading.

Comment: Are you using javascript? If so, look into window.scrollTo()

Comment: I try. Just an artist.

Comment: Ok. Do you have a developer working with you? Or did they ask you to design graphics and code the website?

Comment: Ryan, that's good. I dit it with a botton. Now I want it to do it with body onload

Comment: Have you any experience with script items in your page?

Comment: OK Rayen thank you. body onload="scrollWin()" and function scrollWin() {window.scrollTo(x,y) did it.

Comment: Ok good. Please mark my answer as accpeted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the script tag portion below to the head tag section of your html page, then on your body element, you can add the attribute onload and make it equal to the name of your function which does the scrolling, I would do this a lot differently but since you have no experience coding, I would recommend this simplistic approach.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ScrollOnLoad(){
            window.scrollTo();
        }
</script>

 <body onload="ScrollOnLoad();">
```